# "hundreds times" or "hundreds of times"

Tags: sentence

Can anybody explain how to use "times" properly.

"I've done this hundreds times."
or
"I've done this hundreds of times."

Maybe it is difference between British and American.

Comment: Use either "a hundred times" or "hundreds of times". The same goes for "a thousand times" or "thousands of times". There is no difference between BrE and AmE (that I am aware of).

Comment: "Hundreds times--" is only acceptable if you're multiplying, as in "hundreds times forty"; It would mean (x)100 x 40.

Comment: Mick is incorrect. In British English you would use, "hundreds of times." Without the "of" it makes no sense,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct phrase usage is "a hundred times." One does not say "hundreds times" for the same reason one does not say "twenties times" or "dozens times."

"I've done this a hundred times." - indicates an action that has literally, or approximately, been done one hundred times.

"I've done this hundreds of times." - Mainly used as a hyperbole.